# How to mount zfs-fuse earlier in boot sequence so I can do rsyslog there on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount, zfs

I'm trying to use zfs-fuse as the file system driver for a read/write partition that includes system logging on an Ubuntu 12.04 distribution.  I have succesfully redirected rsyslog there by modifying the appropriate configuration files.  However, on bootup, rsyslog starts way before the zfs-fuse drive is mounted, so it just happily creates the directory, and starts logging on the root partition, and when zfs-fuse tries to mount the drive later in the boot sequence, there are already files there on the / mounted drive where the OS is running and so zfs-fuse can't mount the drive there.  Before I modified rsyslog configuration files to log in a different place, zfs-fuse was automatically mounting the drive just fine.

So, my question is this:

How can I move zfs-fuse mounting of drives to earlier in the boot sequence than rsyslog comes up?  I want rsyslog to contain all the boot information so I can't just move rsyslog to after zfs-fuse, I have to move zfs-fuse earlier.  I can conceive of all kinds of ways to hack this, but I want an elegant solution if one exists.  I've done my fair share of googling on this and can't find anyone who has solved this problem and posted a solution.

Thanks for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 7.5 months later and I finally figured out a clean way to do it so I wanted to post back.

Rsyslog is configured on 12.04 as an upstart job.

zfs-fuse sets itself up when installed with apt-get install so that it supports the command service zfs-fuse start.

Using these two facts, I did the following:

- Added line "service zfs-fuse start" directly after line pre-start script in /etc/init/rsyslog.conf
- Ran command sudo initctl reload-configuration

Now, before rsyslog can start, I'm forcing zfs-fuse service to start which in turn mounts the zfs drives.  Now, I can be confident that barring a failure in the zfs-fuse mount that when rsyslog starts that the zfs-fuse drive will be mounted and ready to be written to allowing me to log there from the very start of the boot process.